# Not able to debug Unit Test

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing

I referred to this question : [Cannot debug a unit testing project in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594018/cannot-debug-a-unit-testing-project-in-visual-studio-2012)

None of the solutions provided there worked from me. I am not seeing anything under test explorer. Whenever i try to debug/Run tests [Using Menu or right click], everytime it shows Build succeeded. Until  now, i was able to debug/run the desired methods.

I have not changed anything. Any clues?

Comment: What unit testing platform are you using?

Comment: @Landeeyo : I am working on Inbuilt test project(we add using Unit test project template) in .NET . No other tools used.

Comment: _"I am not seeing anything under test explorer"_ - what is in the Output window?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether:

- Test class is public
- Test method is public
- Test class has TestClass attribute
- Test method has TestMethod attribute
- Test class has build action Compile set in file properties

You could try also to run Visual Studio as Administrator.

Moreover check this out (even if it's for 2013): [http://blog.sdbarker.com/how-to-fix-visual-studio-2013-not-seeing-unit-tests/](http://web.archive.org/web/20140829112347/http://blog.sdbarker.com/how-to-fix-visual-studio-2013-not-seeing-unit-tests)

Comment: I verified each and everything you told me. I don't understand that no one talks about this over internet. Is it only me or what? Confused. Any other clues?

Comment: I appreciate your effort,but it also didn't solve the issue. Do you think reinstalling Visual Studio would help?

Comment: I assume you have restarted VS and PC and cleaned the solution... I'd first try to run the solution on the other PC. I'd try also to prepare some basic unit test in nUnit or xUnit and install add-on for running them so you can verify it the test explorer works at all. You could also try to add a new test project to the solution.